# Newton's Ring Experiment

Tags: interference

In Newton's ring experiment, it is said that the Newton's ring experiment is used to explain this phenomena as depicted in the image.
[image]

Now, the interference pattern here is forming on the surface of the lens itself.
[image]

But here in this case the reflected rays will meet and interfere on a screen finally instead of interfering on the lens itself or the region between the lens and the flat glass slab. So how are the rings seen on the lens explained by this phenomena?

[image]

or where are the rings formed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interference doesn't just happen in one place. In the photo, you perceive the fringes as occurring at the surface of the lens, because they're framed by the outline of the lens. In reality, the interference happens everywhere that the reflected rays travel. When the photo was taken, the interference was happening both at the surface of the lens and at the imaging chip of the camera (as well as everywhere in between).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer has enlightened me a lot in almost all cases of interference.